# Flutter call setState of parent from child

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help. I need call setState of parent from child
but I'm getting error: The instance member 'updatestate' can't be accessed in an initializer.

So My Parent Widget:

```
class NavbarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavbarPageState createState() => _NavbarPageState();
}

int count_cart = 0;

class _NavbarPageState extends State<NavbarPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  void updatestate (){
    setState(() {
        count_cart+=1;
    });
  }

  int currentPageIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(callback: updatestate),
    ),
  ];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text(''),
      actions: [
        GestureDetector(
          child: badges.Badge(
            badgeContent: Text(count_cart.toString()),
            child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
          ),
          onTap: () {   },
        ),
      ],),
    body: IndexedStack(
      index: currentPageIndex,
      children: pages,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          currentPageIndex = index;
        });
      },
      selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,

      destinations: const <Widget>[
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_sharp),
          label: 'Main',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}
```

and child widget:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  final Function callback;
  HomePage({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center (child:ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          widget.callback();
        }, child: Text('click')),);
  }
}
```

but I'm get error on ParentWidget:
The instance member 'updatestate' can't be accessed in an initializer.
on line: HomePage(callback: updatestate),
scoured the internet looking for a solution. but doesn't help or i can't

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you're trying to access the `updatestate` function and `count_cart` variable from the NavbarPage widget in the HomePage widget, but `count_cart` variable is defined outside the scope of the NavbarPage widget class.

To fix this, you can move the count_cart variable inside the _NavbarPageState class where it belong. Here's the modified code:

```
class NavbarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavbarPageState createState() => _NavbarPageState();
}

class _NavbarPageState extends State<NavbarPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  int count_cart = 0; // Move count_cart here

  void updatestate (){
    setState(() {
        count_cart+=1;
    });
  }

  int currentPageIndex = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(callback: () => updatestate()),// Pass updatestate as a callback
    ),
  ];

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text(''),
      actions: [
        GestureDetector(
          child: badges.Badge(
            badgeContent: Text(count_cart.toString()),
            child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
          ),
          onTap: () {   },
        ),
      ],),
    body: IndexedStack(
      index: currentPageIndex,
      children: pages,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          currentPageIndex = index;
        });
      },
      selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,

      destinations: const <Widget>[
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_sharp),
          label: 'Main',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. I move count_cart but same error. The instance member 'updatestate' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: Ok. Then issue is that you're trying to access the instance member (updatestate) while initializing the HomePage widget, which is not allowed in Dart.
To solve this, you can pass the updatestate function as a callback to the HomePage widget from the NavbarPage widget's build method. I have updated the code. Please try that.

Comment: thanks for the advice. But still the same error

Comment: Yeah!   
I had to move List <> pages between Build and return